# C++ constructor call variations

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

In the following code

```
template <typename T> struct Maybe {
    T* context;

    Maybe(T *context) : context{context} {} .... }
```

What is the difference between declaring

```
Maybe(T *context) : context{context} {} .... }
```

and

```
Maybe(T *context) : context(context) {} .... }
```

?

Both options compile and run without problems.

Comment: In this context (hah) they're the same.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the former is [direct-list-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). The latter is [direct-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization). In this case, they both do the same thing.